# What shevet is Yiftach from? Who are אַנְשֵׁ֣י גִלְעָ֔ד?

Tags: shoftim--book-of, yiftach

In [Shoftim Perek 12](https://www.sefaria.org/Judges.12?lang=bi), it speaks of the people of גִלְעָ֔ד. Who are these people? They fight against the people of Ephraim and I am just confused which shevet they are from?

Additionally, it says in [12:6](https://www.sefaria.org/Judges.12.6?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) that 42,000 men of Ephraim were killed by the people of Gilad. Since Yiftach was the leader of Gilad, was this happening with his permission? Did he support the killings of Ephraim?

Lastly, I thought Yiftach was a Shofet for Bnei Yisroel as a whole, but it seems he did not rule over Ephraim?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%A4%D7%AA%D7%97_%D7%94%D7%92%D7%9C%D7%A2%D7%93%D7%99 most likely menashe

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the face of it, Gilad is in the territory of Menashe (Deuteronomy 3:15) and Menashe had a grandson named Gilad (Numbers 26:29). Since Yiftach is described as the son of Gilad (Judges 11:1), it would seem obvious that all these people are from the tribe of Menashe. That is the generally accepted position.

That said, Rashi (Sukkah 27b) says he doesn't know for sure what tribe Yiftach was from, and Ramban (Genesis 49:19) speculates that he may have been from the tribe of Gad who also inherited cities in the area of Gilad (Joshua 13:25).

Answer (score 1):

According to סדר הדורות הקצר on p.25 it says that he came from the tribe of Menashe.

[image]

Comment: Can I ask why the downvote pls?